# Extract a text from a file c#

Tags: c#, email, visual-studio-2013, streamreader

I got a file .mail that contains:

`

```
FromFild=xxx@gmail.com
ToFild=yyy@gmai.com
SubjectFild=Test
Message=
<b><font size="3" color="blue">testing</font> </b>
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Question</th>
    <th>Answer</th>
    <th>Correct?</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>What is the capital of Burundi?</td>
    <td>Bujumburra</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>What is the capital of France?</td>
    <td>F</td>
    <td>Erm... sort of</td>
</tr>
</table>
  Message=END

 #at least one empty line needed at the end!
```

`

And i need to extract and save only the text that is between Message= and Message=END.
I tried with split('=').Last/First(). Not good.I can not use Substring, as it accepts only int ofIndex. I am noob and i can not think of a sollution. Can you give a hint, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that there is no constant number of lines in the text file or in the message your'e looking for that I can rely on.

```
        string prefix = "Message=";
        string postfix = "Message=END";

        var text = File.ReadAllText("a.txt");
        var messageStart = text.IndexOf(prefix) + prefix.Length;
        var messageStop = text.IndexOf(postfix);
        var result = text.Substring(messageStart, messageStop - messageStart);
```

Comment: Your method is great, but i forgot to mention one fact. It happens to have a few more lines after the Message=END in some .mail files and in that situation   "messageStop - messageStart" will be negative, and a exception will be thrown.

Comment: messageStart will receive the index of the first occurrence of the prefix in the text so this shouldn't happen. Are you in fact parsing multiple batches of Messages?

Comment: I got 3 .mail files. One is ending at Message=END. The others finish with #at least one empty line needed at the end!. I open and read them individually, but the messageStart=356 and messageStop=348, so i will get a negative value that will give me the exception.

Comment: Done. It was my mistake. I used file.ReadToEnd(), instead of FIle.ReadAllText(files[i]).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this Regular Expression :

```
/Message=(?<messagebody>(.*))Message=END/s
```

Then the code to get message :

```
string fileContent; //The content of your .mail file
MatchCollection match = Regex.Matches(fileContent, "/Message=(?<messagebody>(.*))Message=END/s");
string message = match[0].Groups["messagebody"].Value;
```

Comment: I get an exception like "Specified argument was out of the range of valid values." . And match is null, do not know why, i am still trying to figure it out.